# Showing Custom fields values

Tags: php, custom-fields

I'm trying to display custom fields on my site , but unable to return any values in the front-end.

First I added this function to functions.php :

```
function get_custom_field($custom_field) {
    global $post;
    $custom_field = get_post_meta($post ->ID, custom_field, true) ;
    return $custom_field ,
}
```

In my page.php I added this :

```
<?php if ( function_exists('get_custom_field') ) {
    get_custom_field('distance', true) ;  
} ?>
```

The "distance" field is the custom field that I created and want to be displayed.

Any direction would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you miss the $ symbol in the custom_field?
Fix:

```
$custom_field = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field, true);
```

in the calling function you need to use only one parameter. As can i see, you have only one param in the function, the code:

```
<?php if ( function_exists('get_custom_field') ) {
    get_custom_field('distance') ;  } ?>
```

Comment: And `,` instead of `;` in the return instruction.